# UITextField cursor scrolling

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I have a UITextField that is programmatically created. I face the problem where my last character is not shown if the text exceeds the length of the textfield.
How can I show the last character entered and shift the text to the left?

It all works perfectly fine for my other UITextFields created in storyboards. I couldn't find an answer for the question.
Also, it I need to use textField not textView because I would have to change a lot of things.

Thanks!

Comment: check your UI fit for the screen

Comment: Follow @Anbu and check the constraints as well!

Comment: Try this
textField.minimumFontSize = 12
textField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

Comment: Nishant Bhindi, thanks! But I already tried that and it is not working for me. I have font size of 17 and I set minimumFontSize = 17 and adjust it, but it is not working..